# complete Simplification

Tags: algebra-precalculus

given $(n+m)!/((2!)((n+m)-2)!)$

This this the farthest one can simplify this

$(n+m)((n+m)-1))/(2)$

If not How would you foil the top part out?

I'm trying to prove that two statements are equivalent but I can't seem to simplify this to look like the statement I want.

Comment: $(n+m)!=(n+m) \times (n+m-1) \times (n+m-2)!$

Comment: I realize that, that how I was able to cancel the ((n+m)-2)!

Comment: One can manipulate the top further, for example to $(m+n)^2-(m+n)$, However, the expression as a product is likely to be more useful.

Comment: the other side of the statement I have simplified to $((n^2) -n + (m^2)-m +2n) *m$ the things is once I foil out the part that I posted all I get is$ (m^2)+(n^2)-n-m+2mn$ so This proves the statement is not equivalent however, The question states that It is true.